# Why pre-identified Cell is invalid in Sub viewcontroller? iOS

Tags: swift

There is a ViewController as the root view controller, and I want to add a TableViewController as a sub view controller, all these 2 controllers are pre-designed in Story Board. In TableViewController story board, I set the table view as Dynamic, add 1 custom cell and set its Identifier as "cellReuse" .

In the root view controller code, I add TableViewController as Sub ViewController and add it's tableview as Subview, like:

```
var vcSubViewController:MyTableViewController
vcSubViewController = MyTableViewController()
vcSubViewController.delegate = self
self.addChildViewController(vcSubViewController)
self.addSubView(vcSubViewController.tableview)
```

In  tableview controller code:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     ....   
let  cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuse", for: indexPath)
     ....
    }
```

, when running, a error showed that the cannot find Reuse Identifier.

To fix this problem, I have to create a UITableViewCell by code, seems the cell I designed in Story Board has not been realized.May I know what's the wrong? Cheers!

Comment: Did you do this in `viewDidLoad` of TVC: `tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellReuse")` ?

Comment: `MyTableViewController()` is not how you instantiate a view controller from a storyboard, that's why it can't find the cell prototype. Use `storyboard.instantiateViewController...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmilioPelaez is right, you need to instantiate from storyboard or xib to include the identifiers defined in storyboard/IB.

```
if let childVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Something", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewController") as? MyTableViewController {

     childVC.delegate = self
     self.addChildViewController(childVC)
     self.view.addSubView(childVC.tableview)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addChild(_:)` method you use in your code is intended to be called by the system when you use a container view controller. You can not directly call it that way. You can override the method (with calling `super` from it), but in general, what you want to achieve (as far as I understand, you want to embed a view controller with a table view inside of another view controller) can be achieved by using a container view controller.